# how to find similar images by using CNN model

Tags: python, hash, deep-learning, similarity

The requirement of my task is to find the similar output image with the input image in the CNN. There are about half millions images need to be handled with
, it would not realistic to label each image. Beyond that, the images are candlestick charts about all stocks, so it is also very hard to classify all images.

My basic idea is that  exporting the key features of images in CNN and comparing these features by using Hashing algorithm to get the similar one. But the idea was not compeleted, and how to done it in the python is also a big challenge. Therefor, is there anyone can help me with this issue,Thank you very much!!. If possible could you give me any relative articles or codes?

Comment: SO is not a coding service, rather a place to get help with code you are working on.  That being said, you may want to look into [perceptual hashing.](http://tech.jetsetter.com/2017/03/21/duplicate-image-detection/)

Comment: You got a wrong assumption stating it is very hard to solve and not even tried it. There are tons of ways now to solve the above problem and you need to read more documentation on deep learning on how to solve it.

Comment: thanks for your comment ! i know there are many effictive ways to handle the question, like Hashing and CBIR. But i just wondering how can i done it in the deep leanring model, if i want to go through superviced learning, how can i label images ?

Answer (score 0):

Mind reading this

https://towardsdatascience.com/find-similar-images-using-autoencoders-315f374029ea

This uses autoencoders to find similar images.

Please do post the final output code that you will apply so that i have better understand also.